# Nuxt.js SSG (Static site generator) fetch API data

Tags: vue.js, static, nuxt.js, generator, ssg

When building a project with the static site generator, I understand that the document created in advance is provided to the user.

If there is a logic that fetches data using axios, etc. and displays it on the screen when entering the page, does the corresponding API get cached or not called?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 lifecycle hooks that you can use to fetch data: `fetch` and `asyncData` as shown here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching

Depending on how you organize your project and what you need, there will be content generated in advanced thanks to SSG and some of it can also be run on the client, like if you need some auth'ed content.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you use `full static` mode. In this mode, Nuxt does not call `asyncData` and `fetch` because all data must be loaded in the generation step.
https://nuxtjs.org/announcements/going-full-static/#current-issues
You can remove `target: 'static'` from your `nuxt.config.js` and call `nuxt generate`. You get generated static but asyncData`and`fetch` must be available.

Comment: What? This will produce the same result.

Comment: Yes, it seems that `static` is the default state. We get a warning in the generation process but all static is created.